# In SQL Plus updating the query and not commit and guide me to commit in another session

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I was updating the statement in Sqlplus and not commit the code. I am using exit to the terminal.

It is a simple update statement only but I am not commit the code.

Example:  I was connected to SQL Plus using username and password.

```
UPDATE USER SET Name='Daniel' WHERE Name='Francis';
exit
```

Could you please guide me How to commit in another session or 
Could you please update the possible suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`USER`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_keywd001.htm#SQLRF55621) is a reserved keyword in `SQLPLUS`, you should use escape character.

**Commit:**

```
 set exitcommit off
 UPDATE "USER" SET Name='Daniel' WHERE Name='Francis';
 exit
```

Comment: USER means the USER Table.

Comment: yes, put escape characters `"[column_name]"` on it.

Comment: I update the query in the user table but not commit the transaction and exit the session usng exit keyword.How do I commit this transaction in another session

Comment: I already updated the query and this session is in the session table with space manager:slave idle wait the status as actve.
Now,How will I take the session using session id and commit in another session.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Oracle [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4010.htm), at least for version 10g, if your program quits without committing (and you haven't turned on autocommit), the transaction is automatically rolled back. Transactions are isolated at the session level so it is not possible to commit from a different session.

One thing I am uncertain on is whether a DDL statement will commit from a different session. The documentation suggests that a DDL statement forces a commit but it is not clear on the behavior across sessions. Most likely, a DDL statement will be blocked by another session's transactions, but it might be worth trying out.

> If you do not explicitly commit the transaction and the program
>   terminates abnormally, then the last uncommitted transaction is
>   automatically rolled back.